# aws api gateway adding more request parameters has no effect

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

My `API gateway` inkoves a `lambda` function by passing the event with request parameters. 
I'm trying to add few more request params to the existing api gateway through terraform and applied the changes successfully, but by inkoving the api with all the `request parameters` (existing and newly added), the event object that passed to the invoked lambda doesn't have the newly added request params.

Do I need to delete the entire api gateway and re-create with newly added params?

Comment: Did you try redeploying your API gateway ? Every time you change the API you need to deploy a new version

Comment: yes, it got resolved after redeploy.

Answer (score 0):

It got resolved by redeploying API gateway.